# jquery selector and click event not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get a jquery selector to work and give a response on `console.log()` on click however I cant seem to get it working.

Here is [url](http://garden.paperfish.co/index.php/problem-solving/roses)

Code is:

```
$("div#tabs > div#problem-categories > div > div a").click(function() {
    console.log('pass');
});
```

any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: it actually works for me, but I would say soyuka answer with the shorter selector and the preventDefault() should help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to prevent the link from beeing submitted, try this :

```
$("#problem-categories a").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('pass');
});
```

Comment: thanks, used this along with $(document).ready(function() now it works!

Answer (score 1):

This works good for me:

```
$("div#tabs > div#problem-categories > div > div a").on("click", function () {
    console.log('pass');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$("div#problem-categories div.scrollbox").find('a').click(function(ev) {
   ev.preventDefault(); // <-----use this to prevent the jump 
   console.log('pass');
});
```

You have to traverse through this way. `Get into problem-categories' scrollbox` and `find a` in it and `do the click`.

#### [FIND IN FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MuNaT/)

Comment: Its okay but `find` is faster in terms of performance i read somewhere.

Comment: faster then simple dom parsing like `.scrollbox a` ? I doubt that.

Comment: Well your answer just does that.

Comment: `.find()` can be faster in some specific circumstances, but it certainly isn't in this case. http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-selector-test